# Cambiar color icono por cada elemento de Lista en Angular. con *ngFor

Tags: angular, lista, ngfor, li

Tengo el siguiente código en donde itero información mediante la directiva *ngFor.

```
 <ul>
   <li *ngFor="let item of ItemResult.TotalizeCardProduct"  style="list-style-type:none;" class="fa fa-spinner" style="font-size:15px;color:green">
     <strong >{{ item.TotalPoints | number }} Pts</strong>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Lo datos los acomodo en una lista mediante el elemento `<ul> <li>`.
lo cual me genera una lista de 3 datos

Pero en cuanto al ícono fa fa-spinner  me lo genera del mismo color me gustaría poder tener un color identificador por cada elemento de mi lista.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda, es libre si hay alguna otra opcion.

Gracias

Comment: que tal si agregas en tu item el icono que quieres y el color, tu class quedaria algo como `class="fa-{{item.icon}}; color:{{item.color}}" `

Comment: @JackNavaRow La idea es cambiar el icno mediante la iteración sin afectar los elementos del Item, que se encuentran en una interfaz, ajena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
   <ul *ngFor="let item of ItemResult.TotalizeCardProduct; let  i = index">
                <li style="list-style:none;">
                  <!-- <strong>{{ item.Product }}</strong> -->
                  <span class="fa fa-ioxhost" [ngStyle]="{'font-size':'24px','color':getColorCard(i)}"></span>
                  <strong>{{ item.TotalLitters | number }} Ltrs</strong>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

y del lado de TypeScript genere el siguiente metodito:

```
  getColorCard(d: number) {
let color: string;
switch (d) {
  case 0:
    return color = '#000000';
  case 1:
    return color = '#1e98e4';
  case 2:
    return color = '#ff2a00';
  case 3:
    return color = '#008000';
}
```

}

Publico la respuesta porque considero puede ser útil a alguien más.